# ubuntu touch appears to not boot on nexus 10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I have followed the instructions on how to install ubuntu on a nexus 10 as found here

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

but following 'install ubuntu' step 4 - waiting for the reboot, my device shows a cute picture of a microchip and says 'this phone needs restoring from a pc or service center'. There is a progress bar that is moving...

Has this failed, or do I need to wait an very long time for the system to reboot?

What should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I faced the problem, this worked :-

On Nexus 10, after unlocking the bootloader (fastboot oem unlock), the internal storage is left unformatted and must be formatted with-
$ fastboot format cache
$ fastboot format userdata

follow all the remaining steps to flash your nexus 10 and ubuntu should run just fine.

Comment: Here I am again; this worked for me on my nexus 7

Answer (score 2):

I got exact same problem.

I have nexus 4 running android lollipop, installed ubuntu touch, and failed: this phone needs restoring from a pc or service center. So I went back to android, couldn't get lollipop, so used kitkat, because I didn't want to download again (I had kitkat files on PC long before) So with kitkat installed, tried installing ubuntu again, and everything went right.
So in conclusion, at least my case, you have to install ubuntu from a non lollipop android.
I used:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
```

to flash
(all androids mentioned are stock)

Comment: This worked for me (also Nexus 4), used the 4.4.4 firmware from Google.