# This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my nexus 4 and I am getting this error:

```
This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center.
```

Comment: You bricked it.  What are we suppose to do about it?! Fixing this would require physical access to your Nexus and most of us will not be willing to visit you ;)

Comment: Maybe you are lucky and I was wrong: http://askubuntu.com/questions/582151/ubuntu-touch-appears-to-not-boot-on-nexus-10/583189#583189 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must be on kitkat (4.4.4) or earlier to flash Ubuntu Touch.  If you are on Lollipop (5.0 or 5.0.2) you will get this failure.  Fastboot flash the kitkat factory image first, then you will be able to successfully flash Ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this message while trying to flash an updated Ubuntu Touch image, but I already had Ubuntu installed, not android. Here's how I recovered:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit out of any `ubuntu-device-flash` process still running.
- Turn the nexus 4 off (hold down power until the screen goes black).
- Enter fastboot mode (while holding down the volume-down button, press and hold the power button until fastboot mode appears. This appears as an android robot with it's cover open).
- Use `ubuntu-device-flash` to try again. Specifically I used:

  ```
  ubuntu-device-flash touch --bootstrap --developer-mode --channel ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed
  ```

Please note that the above will completely wipe your device and install the latest devel-proposed image (currently 15.04). If this is not what you want, refer to `ubuntu-device-flash -h` to see the available options.

Comment: --developer-mode is not needed, if all you want to do is recover your phone to a known state.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this lots of times.  When you perform the device flash command, on your phone you will eventually come to prompt with a few options like reboot in recovery mode, restore device, etc.  Don't select anything!  If you select any of the options, you will likely get that error after the phone reboots automatically.  Just leave it alone and be patient, it will sit on that screen for several minutes before auto-reboot.

If it lingers on that prompt screen indefinitely, restart the process of device flash, by booting in the boot loader again, except before you run the device flash command, use your volume buttons to select "Recovery" mode in the boot loader - this is option in big letters in the top part of the screen - then commence with device flash.  You may still get the other prompt again, but again, do nothing, just be patient.