# Ubuntu Touch Issues, cant install on Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Trying to install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7 (2013) but when I get to the last step I run into a problem... I am using the guide here --->>> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

I am installing it using the latest version of Ubuntu on Virtualbox.

It successfully downloads the files.... all looks good...

```
matt@matt-ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=devel --bootstrap
2015/05/19 21:49:48 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/05/19 21:50:41 Device is |flo|
2015/05/19 21:50:43 Flashing version 2 from devel channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device flo
3.95 MB / 3.95 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 107.76 KB/s 
46.55 MB / 46.55 MB [==================================] 100.00 % 206.71 KB/s 
332.41 MB / 332.41 MB [================================] 100.00 % 280.12 KB/s
```

and then this... `Failed to enter Recovery`

I am in fastboot and unlocked, isn't that right?

Can't figure out where to go from here, any suggestions?

Comment: I was stuck at the same point with a Nexus 10. This helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591828/this-phone-needs-restoring-from-a-pc-or-service-center.
You might be running into something similar. Hope it helps...