# Can not install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I am having a lot of trouble installing Ubuntu onto my Nexus 10 (16gb wifi edition). I have followed the instructions [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) and [here](https://devices.ubports.com/#/manta). No matter what I do it ends with the message 'this phone needs restoring from a pc or service center'. I have searched ask ubuntu and other forums and here is what I have tried to solve the problem. Installed android 4.4.4 stock, cyanogenmod 11, android 4.0 stock prior to flashing. I also formatted with

```
$ fastboot format cache
$ fastboot format userdata
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582151/ubuntu-touch-appears-to-not-boot-on-nexus-10). Nothing seems to work.

Other things to note, I am using ubuntu-device-flash on a virtual box machine running ubuntu 16.04, and it takes a long time for ubuntu-device-flash to push the last .tar.xz file to my tablet, somewhere in the range of 1 hour or more. Last night I let it run overnight because some on some forums the response to similar problems was "be patient" once you see the 'this phone needs restoring...' error. When I woke up the phone was in a boot loop and I had to re-flash stock 4.4.4.

I have successfully flashed ubuntu version 2 with the dual boot app in android, but I can't get it to update. I also have not been successful in getting the app to use the UBports server as a custom server to install the latest version, similar to [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795895/nexus-10-dualboot-ubports-image-with-existing-android).

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Related question, does ANYONE have the latest stable build for Manta running on a Nexus 10, and how did you get to that point??

Answer (score 0):

Official support for the Nexus 10 has been dropped so the images on the server are pretty old, UBport has picked it up: https://devices.ubports.com/#/manta